# I cant get this formula to work correctly in the target cell. What is wrong with my formula notation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cant get this formula to work correctly in the target cell.  What is wrong with my formula notation?

The offending formula, which im trying to generate using the code below, should look like this **=importRange("0Ak-----------------------VkE5M2c","clan members!A1:D172")** in the target cell. but it does not

```js
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ak-----------------------VkE5M2c");
 var insert_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Point Rank Sheet");
 var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("clan members");
 var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
 insert_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);     
 var values = source.getSheetByName("Form Data").getRange("A2:E2").getValues();
 target.getSheetByName("clan members").getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":E"+(last_row+1)).setValues(values);
 var formula_cell = insert_sheet.getRange("A1:A1");
 var formula = '=importRange("0Ak-----------------------VkE5M2c","clan members!A1:D"+(last_row+1))';
 formula_cell.setFormula(formula)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`var formula = '=importRange("0Ak-----------------------VkE5M2c","clan members!A1:D' + (last_row + 1) + '")';`